# Can't Dilate pupils

Tags: animation

I have an eye but I can't dilate the pupils in an animation. It doesn't let the pupils dilate on the animation. It is either dilated or not.

[image]

Comment: Hello, you don't tell a lot, maybe share a screenshot of the material so that someone guess how to do it from your current setup, or even pack your image and share the eye?

Comment: How are you animating the pupal? Is the eye and pupal a single object? If so you'll need to use "Shape Keys" to animate it.